# Highlighting last column in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, column-chart

I have a bar chart which has dynamic columns in it. 
What i want is that except the last column, all the columns should be of grey color. And the last column should be of green.

Can anyone help me out in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`zones`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Ccolumn%3E.zones).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/udL2ads2/6/

```js
$(function() {
  var histSuccess = [100, 99, 100, 98, 98, 99.9, 97.5, 100, 95, 90];

  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Column chart with last column different color'
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: 'Total'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Test',
      color: 'grey',
      data: histSuccess,
      
      zoneAxis: 'x',
      zones: [{
       value: histSuccess.length - 1.5,
        color: 'grey'
      },{
       color: '#66ff33'
      }]
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can give color to last column in this way

```
series: [{
        name: 'Test',
        color:'grey',
        data: [50, 30, 40, 70, {y: 34, color: '#66ff33'}]
    }]
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/udL2ads2/5/)

So if the data array is dynamic then for the last value of array you have to make last element as `{y: 34, color: '#66ff33'}` of the array.

Comment: This works fine but the problem is that i am using the last member of data for certain calculations. And if i give it as {y: 34, color: '#66ff33'}, i can't do the calculations. So any way where we can define this color outside the "series" tag?

Comment: can you post the way you are creating the array

Comment: Its just a normal array of something like this format: var histSuccess = [100, 99, 100, 98, 98, 99.9, 97.5, 100, 95, 90].

Comment: Updated the fiddle link check it

Comment: So map histSuccess to another array with the proper color (you will get a copy of histSucess) and pass the mapped array to the chart config and do the calculation on original histSuccess.